# R - Primitive - sin

Tags: r, list, primitive

how can I get the primitive of sinus? I figured out that there is a formula called .primitive but I am still struggling...

My task is the following: Create a list with the following elements:

1. element is a list of numbers 32,17,21;
2. element is number 49.41 and
3. is a primitive sin

My solution is

```
list_task <- list(c(32,17,21),49.41,sin.primitive)
```

However, it does not work - can anyone help me?

Comment: You have strange homework. I *suspect*  this is the solution: `list(c(32,17,21),49.41,sin)`

Comment: If you read `help('.Primitive')` you'll conclude that any of `sin` or `.Primitive('sin')` or `get('sin', envir = baseenv())` return the same value, a function. And that `is.primitive(sin)` returns `TRUE`.

Comment: Thanks for this impressively fast response! I will go for the plain sin option!